# Non-breaking space column indexing in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a [`pandas groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/groupby.html) object that contains a column with `&nbsp;` as its name (i.e., non-breaking space). Although the following snippet is able to print it:

```
In[25]: 
   ...: for key, item in grouped_df:
   ...:     print(key)
```

Output:

```
&nbsp;
... other names
```

I'm not able to index it with `grouped_df[key]`:

```
In[29]: 
   ...: for key, item in grouped_df:
   ...:     print(key, grouped_df[key].count())
```

which results in:

```
KeyError: 'Column not found: &nbsp;'
```

---

[Update]

**Partial solution** was to use `.agg(['count'])`. However, that is a solution to that specific example I'm giving, but not the main problem.

---

Here is code which reproduces the problem:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

N = 100
df = pd.DataFrame({'col':np.random.choice([1,2,3,4,'&nbsp;'], size=N),
                   'col2':np.random.randint(10, size=N) })

grouped_df = df.groupby('col')
for key, item in grouped_df:
    print(key)

print(grouped_df['&nbsp;'])
```

Comment: What does `list(grouped_df.groups.keys())` print? Printing a list prints the `repr` of the items it contains. This might reveal invisible characters in the value of `key` which is we don't see when you use `print(key)`.

Comment: `['&nbsp;', .. other names ]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`grouped_df` is a `DataFrameGroupBy` object, not a DataFrame.
To extract a DataFrame from `grouped_df`, use the [`get_group` method](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.get_group.html):

```
In [231]: grouped_df.get_group('&nbsp;')
Out[231]: 
       col  col2
3   &nbsp;     9
9   &nbsp;     2
14  &nbsp;     5
29  &nbsp;     0
30  &nbsp;     4
33  &nbsp;     6
38  &nbsp;     7
41  &nbsp;     0
53  &nbsp;     7
57  &nbsp;     6
73  &nbsp;     8
75  &nbsp;     7
83  &nbsp;     0
92  &nbsp;     1
98  &nbsp;     8
```